# Uncaught ReferenceError: updateCart (functionName) is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was trying to update quantity using Ajax.But before that i tried to print the updated value.  But when i tried to update the quantity i got following Error :

> Uncaught ReferenceError: updateCart is not defined

```
<td class="qty"><input class="form-control input-sm" id="quantity" onchange="updateCart()"  value="{{$row->quantity}}"></td>
<td class="price"><span>&#2547; {{$row->price*$row->quantity}}</span></td>
    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    function updateCart()
    {
       var x = document.getElementById("quantity").value;
        console.log(x);
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you provide the rest of the html or more of it please?

Comment: it's inside td nothing else. I have updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your example that function `updateCart()` does not exist in the global scope. It exists only inside `$(document).ready(function (){ });`, in order to fix that just put `updateCart()` outside of `.ready`.

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="qty">
        <input class="form-control input-sm" id="quantity" onchange="updateCart()">
      </td>

      <td class="price">
        <span>&#2547;</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script>
  function updateCart() {
    var x = document.getElementById("quantity").value;
    console.log(x);
  }
</script>
```

However, there is better solution

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="qty">
        <input type="number" class="form-control input-sm js-quantity" />
      </td>

      <td class="price">
        <span>&#2547;</span>
        <span class="js-price"></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>


<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.js-quantity').on('change', function () {
    console.log($(this).val());
    
    var PRICE = 100;
    $('.js-price').html( +$(this).val() * PRICE )
  });
})
</script>
```

Comment: I heard input type number doesn't work on IE that's why i avoided it. But first one give the right answer.Thanks for that!

Comment: @Hola > input type number doesn't work on IE, 
you can change, `type="number"` to `type="text"` and use second example, it is jQuery way to handle events. thanks.